# Firefox can't find the server at www.localhost.com

Tags: asp.net, localhost

When i run my asp.net application it shows error on web page 
"Firefox can't find the server at WWW.localhost.com"
I am using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate and Windows 7 OS and Browser Firefox
Please Give me super and Permanent solution as much as fast because i have to complete my asp.net project so soon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try using

```
    http://localhost:80/
```

80 is the port number.. change accourdingly
or if u run directly then u have to change the configuration from

```
www.localhost.com to http://localhost
```

Comment: configure that to same

Comment: http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2012/04/aspnet-host-website-on-local-machine.html hope this will help

Comment: sorry it will not ork

Comment: Check your hosts file, it should be redirecting localhost to 127.0.0.1 and nothing else. The entry that will cause this error should look like this:

127.0.0.1    www.localhost.com
If you find this, remove it or change www.localhost.com to localhost.


127.0.0.1
http://localhost

Comment: that's my default url

Comment: http://www.fpweb.net/support/hosting-basics/edit-hostfile/ hope this helps please include 127.0.0.1 localhost:1030/SimpleBlog

Answer (score 1):

I hope you are putting the URL in a correct way i.e., `http://localhost:portnumber`

If you are doing above correctly and page is still NOT showing, this maybe due to some proxy you maybe using. See the below image, highlighted option is showing that I don't want proxy to resolve my loopback addresses.

This is also possible that you are using Internet Explorer's settings for proxy, the same option also present in internet explorer.

[image]

Comment: how can do in firefox??